# Why are "Cast Close/Re-open Votes" privilege based on Overall reputations?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges, tag-badges

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027229/given-a-number-generate-a-series-of-l-shaped-matrix-with-matlab) is a question i asked recently. After few minutes, i got a down vote. Also after some time, it was closed stating that "**the question was too broad**"   (The question is now reopened. You might look at the edit history to see them)

If you look at the comments for the same question, you would know that the question was clear and useful as said by a 50k+ rep user. Also the answers provided were very very short. In no way should the question be considered *Broad*.

The persons who voted to close are well rep-ed users. I got confused as of why this type of things happen. They all were highly ranked on different languages and tags. Seems like they didn't see the question from the specific language (Matlab in this case) point of view. Maybe they didn't knew that, with [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab), this is some ordinary, very easily solvable question.

My question is, Why are "Cast Close/Re-open Votes" privilege based on Overall reputations? Why can't that be tag based? like a bronze or silver badge on specific tag has the right to "Cast Close/Re-open Votes" similar to the persons owning a gold badge on specific tag who can mark duplicates on the same tag single handedly.

Is there any loop-hole to this proposal? Or is there any other way around?

Comment: If it's based on tags alone then there would be no possibility of doing anything in newer tags. Whether that's bad or not would change depending on who you talk to.

Comment: While lack of experience in a tag certainly leads to some bad situations like this, IMO most of the cases for closing and re-opening are very clear cut.  In the same way I am able to triage most questions based on their content, the close/re-open voters can accurately judge the state of a question.

Comment: May be this is a bad question. but may i know why the original question in SO gets down Voted now?? Doing it might fear new users here to post new questions.

Comment: You didn't put a lot of effort into your question. You posted a problem statement without posting what you had tried. "Does not show any research effort" is one of the primary reasons for downvoting.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, actually that was part of a bigger question and i was stuck at that particular part and had no idea to that thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In no way should the question be considered Broad.

You asked for the best way to do something, and you didn't provide any indication of what you had tried so far. That leaves us open to a lot of possibilites, which some people may think is too broad.

In 99% of cases, you don't need any particular expertise in a tag to tell if a question is off-topic or not. Add to that the fact that most people on the site don't have silver or even bronze badges in a wide array of tags, and implementing your proposal would eliminate the majority of potential close-voters with no real benefit. Some of the lower-traffic tags wouldn't have anyone who qualifies to cast a close vote at all.

Comment: Ok.. i completely agree.. May be this is a bad question. but may i know why the original question in SO gets down Voted now?? I'm afraid new users like me (in meta) might fear posting new questions if the same happens.

Comment: @SanthanSalai See my comment on your question above.

Comment: @SanthanSalai this is the "meta effect". You linked your question here, so more people will see it now, and act as they see fit. You admit it's a bad question, and now you have more people who view it... so yes, you can expect more downvotes

Comment: @Patrice, Ok.. do i have have the privilege to remove my question as i know where i was wrong?

Comment: @Santhan: Why don't you just edit it into a better question?